# Cobol MCH3601 error when calling C program

Tags: c, ibm-midrange, cobol

there is a MCH3601 when calling a C program in COBOL multiple times. In the first calls, it works well, but then it fails with that error ([MCH3601](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/clarification-why-message-mch3601-or-mch0601-received-application))...  I call the C program like this

```
CALL "C2" USING BY REFERENCE RESULT-STRING.
```

The strange thing is that if I call a different C program before the call that fails, then the call that was failing works well. I am familiar with bugs in C in which you put an additional printf and everything works, and those are because you are allocating memory poorly and the fact of using a printf allocates more space in the stack for the return address of the printf  and its parameters, so your bad code works because is overflowing over the printf stuff so no segmentation fault.

I guess this is something similar, but in cobol I have variable declarations like this

```
01  RESULT-STRING    PIC X(20)       VALUE ALL "X".
```

So I believe that should allocate the resources it needs. Also I have no idea about as400 assembly and I am somewhat ignorant in as400 so I am struggling to tackle the problem. Thanks for any help.

--EDIT

to answer comments:
The C program returns an int. It is defined as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The argument is obtained as

```
char * myarg=argv[1];
```

and then other string is copied into it:

```
char * other_string[100];
...
//I null terminate it at byte 16
other_string[15]=0;
//the strcpy will copy only 15 bytes plus null char into the referenced arg
strncpy(myarg, other_string,16);
return 0;
```

So I believe I am not writing over something outside the referenced cobol variable in C in any way. The Cobol code is rather large and it does multiple calls in different places.

Is it possible to have an overflow in Cobol that mess the return address of the call or something like that?

Comment: Just guessing as the C piece is missing: do you put something in there that is bigger than the char[20], for example a C string with a length of 20? What return type does the C code have (void/int/...) - and does this match the expectation of the CALL CONVENTION from the COBOL side?

Comment: Show your C code, at least the part that is dealing with the variable passed by reference.

Comment: see edit please

Comment: Is the MCH3601 in the COBOL program or the C program? If it's in the COBOL program, does the error happen on one of the CALL statements, or some other statement?

Comment: I can't identifiy if it's in the C or Cobol, because in this reference https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/clarification-why-message-mch3601-or-mch0601-received-application  they say "Message MCH3601 happens as a result of storage corruption that might have happened in a previous program CALL. Message MCH0601 occurs when you attempt to write data past the space allocated for your job." So I infer it's how you call it, so I believe it might be in cobol but not sure, it just happen in that line when i do the call

Comment: The joblog should show the program and statement number that got the MCH3601. In DSPJOBLOG, do F10 to see all messages, then do F1 on the MCH3601 to see the whole message and then F9 to see the program and statement number for the message.

Comment: This `char * other_string[100];` declares an array of pointers, not a string, doesn't it? So `other_string[15]=0;` sets the 16th pointer to zero. Not what you wanted, but this alone doesn't cause any wild memory overwritting.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cobol routine passes *one* parameter by reference, i.e. it passed the address of the storage area of variable `RESULT-STRING`. So, your C routine will receive a *single* parameter, i.e. a pointer.

What you assume to be the integer containing the number of arguments passed, *argc*, is actually the address of the single parameter passed by reference. All the references to the *argv* array use arbitary storage adressses, since nothing has been passed.

You need to make sure that the entry point to the C routine is correctly specified, since you call `C2` from Cobol. Your C routine should be declared as:

```
void C2 (char *result-string)
```

Only if the C program is the top-most routine, called form a command line like environment, will it be passed a counter, and an array of char pointers to the arguments given.

## Update

I've coded a sample Cobol routine calling a C routine, passing one parameter by reference. *Note* this was done on z/OS, not AS/400. You man need to adjust to the AS/400 environment.

## Cobol Source

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                     
       PROGRAM-ID. COBTOC.                                          
       AUTHOR.     Peter Hunkeler.                                  
       ENVIRONMENT    DIVISION.                                     
       DATA           DIVISION.                                     
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                     
                                                                    
       01  Some-Char-String   PIC X(20) value is 'Hello from Cobol'.
       01  C-SubRoutine       PIC X(8) VALUE 'CFROMCOB'.            
                                                                    
       PROCEDURE      DIVISION.                                     
                                                                    
           DISPLAY 'About to call subroutine ' C-SubRoutine.        
           DISPLAY 'Passing Some-Char-String: ' Some-Char-String.   
           CALL C-SubRoutine USING BY REFERENCE Some-Char-String.   
           DISPLAY 'Just returned from ' C-SubRoutine.              
           DISPLAY 'Some-Char-String now is: ' Some-Char-String.    
                                                                    
           MOVE 0 to RETURN-CODE.                                   
           GOBACK.                                                  
                                                                    
       END PROGRAM COBTOC.
```

## C Source

```
#include <stdio.h>                                      
                                                        
void cfromcob( char *pCobString ) {                     
                                                        
 char string[21];                                       
 char returnString[21] = "Returning from C   ";         
                                                        
 printf( "Hello from some C code.\n" );                 
                                                        
 strncpy( string, pCobString, 20);                      
 string[20] = 0x00;                                     
 printf( "This data was passed: %s\n", string );        
                                                        
 strncpy( pCobString, returnString, 20);                
 printf( "This data is returned: %s\n", returnString ); 

 }
```

The C routine was bound with the following BINDER parameters:

```
  ENTRY    CFROMCOB
  NAME     CFROMCOB(R)
```

## Runtime Output

When run, the following lines are seen on the output (SYSOUT):

```
About to call subroutine CFROMCOB             
Passing Some-Char-String: Hello from Cobol    
Hello from some C code.                   
This data was passed: Hello from Cobol    
This data is returned: Returning from C   
Just returned from CFROMCOB                   
Some-Char-String now is: Returning from C
```

Comment: So the standard CALL CONVENTION on z/OS and possibly on AS400 had no return type (void), correct? Can you link to some ibm docs (at least for z/OS) that specified this?

Comment: I concluded that from the Cobol `CALL` statement shown. It doesn't have a `RETURNING` phrase. Standard call convention on z/OS are specified in [z/OS MVS Programming: Assembler Services Guide. Topic "Linkage Convention"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-linkage-conventions). *Note* that these are the conventions at the operation system level, i.e. assembler programs. Specifically, return data, if any, is defined to be placed in register 15, 0, and 1. Conventions for High Level Languages (HLL) add more complexity to returned data.

Comment: I think tthe call is ok, I did like in this example https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=program-sample-code-ile-c-call-example ...

Comment: I tried to read-up on how this works on AS/400 (which is new to me). It seems that my example above would apply if the Cobol and C routines are bound together, as in [Sample Code for ILE C Procedure Call Example 1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=eicpcficp-sample-code-ile-c-procedure-call-example-1). You are referring to the example where both routines are separate programs. Which one are you using?